# Undefined offset error in PHP from json response

Tags: php

The code I wrote supposed to do two things: 1- shows the latest post from a twitter user 2- searches for a specific keyword. For the first part, it works perfectly but it fails in case of 'search' option by dumping this error message:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:

I run the code with this format:

```
$ php script.php search keyword number
```

Here is the code:

```
    $result = file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=$argv[2]&rpp=$argv[3]&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed");
    $decoded = json_decode($result,true);
    for($j=0; $j<$argv[3]; $j++)
    {

    echo ($decoded[$j]['text']);



   }
```

Comment: that error is just a notice it wont stop the code from running, what it means though is that ur trying to use probably an array that hasnt been set, best thing would be `print_r();` whatever arrays your using and see if the contain what they're suppose to

Comment: Probably the array doesn't contain anything. You should check with `isset` or something. What exact line is the error on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked the Twitter response, it doesn't match the format of the array you trying to access.
You can't access the data through `$decoded[$j]['text']` simply because that doesn't exist in the response.

What you mean to do is:

```
$decoded[results][$j]['text']
```

I've checked it and that appears to works fine.

Excerpt from the response (print_r format), you see why it happens.

> ```
> Array (
>   [completed_in] => 0.015
>   [max_id] => 322818055665225728
>   [max_id_str] => 322818055665225728
>   [page] => 1
>   [query] => testsearch
>   [refresh_url] => ?since_id=322818055665225728&q=testsearch&result_type=mixed&include_entities=1
>   [results] => Array
>     (
>       [0] => Array
>         (
>           [created_at] => Fri, 12 Apr 2013 21:06:36 +0000
>           [entities] => Array
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If the user inputs '10' but the query only returns 9 results, the 10th iteration of the for loop will return that notice (as $decoded[9] doesn't exist).

Perhaps try something like this

```
$limit = $argv[3];

if (count($decoded) < $limit)
{
    $limit = count($decoded);
}

for ($j = 0; $j < $limit; $j++)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Probably true, but it is not the root cause of the problem here. He should implement something like this, though.